# Why a std::array is not constant expression when it is the input of a templated function/generic lambda?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, lambda, constexpr

(Realted to [this other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231628/can-i-use-boostcopy-range-on-the-result-of-boostadaptorstransformed-over-s); if you give a look at that too, I would really appreciate it.)

[If `std::array<T,N>::size` is `constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size), then why does the following code not even compile?

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto print_size = [](auto const& array){
    constexpr auto size = array.size();
    std::cout << size << '\n';
};

int main() {
    print_size(std::array<int,3>{{1,2,3}});
}
```

The error is the following:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 deleteme.cpp && ./a.out 
deleteme.cpp: In instantiation of ‘<lambda(const auto:1&)> [with auto:1 = std::array<int, 3>]’:
deleteme.cpp:10:42:   required from here
deleteme.cpp:5:20: error: ‘array’ is not a constant expression
    5 |     constexpr auto size = array.size();
      |                    ^~~~
```

But I wonder why.

At the lambda call site, the argument is known at compile time, and the lambda should be instantiated with `auto` equal to `std::array<int,3>`, where `3` is a compile time value, and so should be output of `array.size()`.

What is wrong in my reasoning?

By the way, the same holds if I use a templated function instead of the generic lambda.

Comment: [`return array.size();`](https://godbolt.org/z/4dqsYe) works though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, this makes the thing even stranger. Proably RVO is bypassing some limitation of the language?

Comment: Indeed. `constexpr size = array.size();` inside the lambda won't work, but returning the same and assigning to a `constexpr` variable does. No idea why there's a diff :-)

Comment: Function parameters are never `constexpr`. Remember that even a `constexpr` function must be callable at run-time.

Comment: @super True, but it does look wierd in a case like this i.m.o.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Indeed. I remember seeing a good article/video about this here on SO somewhere. It goes into a lot more depth and explains why this (not sure if this exact scenario, but at least similar) is not even possible with `consteval`. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: You might use `constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<decltype(array)>>::value`.

Comment: @super, how does Ted Lyngmo's example escape this rule?

Comment: @Enlico It doesn't. The return value doesn't have to be `constexpr`. But if it is, we are allowed to use it as one at the calling site. Which in turn depends on the parameter passed in, but at the calling site the compiler knows if the parameter passed in is a `constexpr` or not as opposed to inside the function definition.

Comment: But doesn't it know at the time of instantiating the generic lambda/template function?

Comment: Sure. But even an instatiated template must be callable at run-time, so that doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Probably I miss some bits. I don't see why the compiler can't instantiate the lambda with `auto` equal to `std::array<some_type, 3>` and then be able to call it at run time too. It's a `std::array`, it won't change size at run time, no?

Comment: @Enlico I'm sure there are duplicates here on SO that goes into more details on this, but I can't seem to find them right now. I can't give you a waterproof answer to that, but I'm 99% sure I've seen it and read it on here somewhere.

Comment: @super, I've come back to this while watching the presentation I've now linked off the self-answer I've just written. Now I understand what you meant. Thank you very much. By the way, is this the video you were referring to in your second comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was watching [the 2014 *Metaprogramming with Boost.Hana: Unifying Boost.Fusion and Boost.MPL* presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/CPP/C-PP-Con-2014/Metaprogramming-with-BoostHana-Unifying-BoostFusion-and-BoostMPL), where Louise Dionne touches this topic and explains what @super was telling me in the comments, but I was not understanding it.

This is my rewording of that concept: there's no such a thing as a `constexpr` function parameter, therefore whenever the lambda (actually its underlying `operator()`) is instantiated for a given type of `array`, that *single* instantiation *is the one* that should work both for `constexpr` and non-`constexpr` arguments of that type.

As Louis Dionne says in the linked presentation,

> […] you can't generate a `constexpr` inside a function if it depends on a parameter […] the return type of a function may only depend on the types of its arguments, not on their values […]

This give a way around the issue. Use `array`'s type without using `array`'s value:

```cpp
constexpr auto print_size = [](auto const& array){
    using array_type = decltype(array);
    constexpr auto size = array_type{}.size();
    std::cout << size << '\n';
};
```

which I think it's not different, in essence, from what @Jarod42 suggested in a comment:

> You might use `constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<decltype(array)>>::value`

As an addition, I played around a bit more, because a last thing was bugging me: the size of `std::array` is not part of the value, but it's part of the *type*, so why can't I call `size` member function in `contexpr`s? The reason is that [`std::array<T,N>::size()` is sadly not `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35988594/5825294). If it was, one could call it as in the commented line below (the `struct A` is for comparison):

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::size_t N>
struct A {
    static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept { return N; }
};
constexpr auto print_size = [](auto const& array){
    constexpr auto size = std::decay_t<decltype(array)>::size();
    std::cout << size << '\n';
};

int main() {
    //print_size(std::array<int,3>{{1,2,3}});
    print_size(A<3>{});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is [[expr.const]/5.12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.12):

> 5 - An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
> [...]
>
> - (5.12) an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
>   - (5.12.1) it is usable in constant expressions or
>   - (5.12.2) its lifetime began within the evaluation of E;

Since the variable `array` is a reference, it is not permitted to evaluate it (inside the expression `array.size()`), even though the evaluation doesn't actually do anything.

Passing `array` by value (`const` or non-`const`) makes the code valid:

```
constexpr auto print_size = [](auto const array){
    constexpr auto size = array.size(); // ok
    std::cout << size << '\n';
};
```

But taking a reference to that parameter and using it on the very next line is invalid:

```
constexpr auto print_size = [](auto const arr){
    auto const& array = arr;
    constexpr auto size = array.size(); // error
    std::cout << size << '\n';
};
```

Note that gcc 9 incorrectly accepts this code; it is only since version 10 that gcc gets this correct.

gcc 10 still is noncompliant in a related area; it accepts calling a `static constexpr` member function on a reference. [Using a constexpr static member of a reference as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710377/using-a-constexpr-static-member-of-a-reference-as-template-argument/51710494#51710494) This is incorrect and clang correctly rejects it:

```
struct S { static constexpr int g() { return 1; } };
void f(auto const& s) {
    constexpr auto x = s.g(); // error
    constexpr auto y = decltype(s)::g(); // ok
}
int main() { f(S{}); }
```

Addendum: this may change in future, per the paper [P2280R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2280r1.html).

Comment: I'm not so sure this answer is correct.  There are no constexpr function parameters so `constexpr auto size = array.size();` should be illegal in all cases. I think the reason it does compile is because the `operator()` is a template (because of `auto`) and an invalid constexpr template does not require any diagnose.

Comment: @NathanOliver well, clang accepts function (non-template) `void print_size(std::array<int, 3> const array)`: https://godbolt.org/z/zKbYvs

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see how `array.size()` called on a (non-`constexpr`) value of type `std::array<int, 3>` violates any provision of http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5 ?

Comment: My issues is that a non-constexpr variable, which is what `array` should be, should not be able to return a constexpr value in which to initialize `size` with.  I don't understand how it's allowing it to be used.

Comment: @NathanOliver `array::size()` is a `constexpr` function that does not access any data members of `array`, and the compiler can see that. It seems fine to me.