# Why can't the .size() of an array passed to a function as a constant reference be used as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, const-reference

I can't seem to figure out why the following code doesn't work:

```cpp
#include <array>

template <long unsigned int s> void a() {}

template <long unsigned int s> void b(const std::array<int, s>& arr) {
    a<arr.size()>(); // error: no matching function for call to 'a'
}


int main() {
    const std::array<int, 2> arr {{0, 0}};
    a<arr.size()>(); // Works
    b<arr.size()>(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC fails with the following:

```cpp
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void b(const std::array<int, s>&) [with long unsigned int s = 2]’:
test.cpp:13:22:   required from here
test.cpp:6:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘a<(& arr)->std::array<int, 2>::size()>()’
    6 |     a<arr.size()>(); // Doesn't
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
test.cpp:3:37: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int s> void a()’
    3 | template <long unsigned int s> void a() {}
      |                                     ^
test.cpp:3:37: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:6:18: error: ‘arr’ is not a constant expression
    6 |     a<arr.size()>(); // Doesn't
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
test.cpp:6:15: note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’
    6 |     a<arr.size()>(); // Doesn't
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~
```

I assume the `‘arr’ is not a constant expression` part is most relevant, but I don't understand why the same line works in `main()` (is it a constant expression there?), and why passing `arr` as a `const` copy (rather than a reference) also resolves the issue.

PS: I know that I can just use `a<s>();`, but I'm just trying to figure out what this error means.

Comment: Function arguments can't be used as constant expressions.

Comment: @cigien If I change b's signature to `void b(const std::array<int, s> arr)` (pass by copy), there is no error. Is that not using a function argument as a constant expression?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936507/why-isnt-stdarraysize-static/35988594#35988594

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't compile. There's probably a correct dupe somewhere, but the one I used isn't, so I've reopened.

Comment: Here's a reasonable [target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236583). It appears that `std::array` passed to a function by *value* can be used as a constant expression, but not if it's passed by *reference*.

Comment: @alfC If the size were static, would this work? Thanks for the context though!

Comment: @cigien I can't say I understand why references specifically can't be a constant expression, but I guess that answers my question (even if only to say that that's just what the standard says). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. Maybe in C++2X, it will work with `consteval` functitons.
1. **For non-reference argument it works** https://godbolt.org/z/Wx9va54z5.
   I think it is fine to pass `std::array` of built-ins by value in general anyway.
   (This works in GCC and clang.)

```
#include <array>

template <long unsigned int s> void a() {}

template <long unsigned int s> void b(std::array<int, s> arr) {
    a<arr.size()>(); // ok
}

int main() {
    const std::array<int, 2> arr = {};
    a<arr.size()>(); // Works
    b<arr.size()>(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

2. To answer the question in your comment @acumandr, yes, a `static` and `constexpr`  `size()` member function in `std::array` would work(!), even for `const&` argument. https://godbolt.org/z/anP1e9qEr

> CORRECTION: This is correct only for GCC, in clang doesn't work https://godbolt.org/z/65d5G9Yfo , Thanks @IlCapitano

```
#include <array>

template<class T, std::size_t D>
struct MyArray{
    static constexpr std::size_t size(){return D;}
};

template <long unsigned int s> void a() {}

template <long unsigned int s> void b(MyArray<int, s> const& arr) {
    a<arr.size()>(); // ok
}

int main() {
    const MyArray<int, 2> arr = {};
    a<arr.size()>(); // Works
    b<arr.size()>(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

which makes even more puzzling why `std::array` doesn't have a static (and constexpr) `size` member.

2.5) CORRECTION: This is correct only for GCC, in clang doesn't work https://godbolt.org/z/65d5G9Yfo , Thanks @IlCapitano

In clang, a static funciton works but not passing the instance, which kind of defeats the purpose:

https://godbolt.org/z/En13aEWPz

```
#include <array>

template<class T, std::size_t D>
struct MyArray{
    static constexpr std::size_t size(){return D;}
};

template <long unsigned int s> void a() {}

template <long unsigned int s> void b(MyArray<int, s> const& arr) {
    a<std::decay_t<decltype(arr)>::size()>(); // error: no matching function for call to 'a'
}

int main() {
    const MyArray<int, 2> arr = {};
    a<arr.size()>(); // Works
    b<arr.size()>(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

3. using `std::tuple_size<decltype(...)>` (or `s` itself) is a good workaround https://godbolt.org/z/K9xxKa1Px

```
#include <array>

template <long unsigned int s> void a() {}

template <long unsigned int s> void b(std::array<int, s> arr) {
    a<std::tuple_size<decltype(arr)>::value /*or just s*/>(); // ok
}

int main() {
    const std::array<int, 2> arr = {};
    a<arr.size()>(); // Works
    b<arr.size()>(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your second example [doesn't work with Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/93asTGPYT).

Comment: @IlCapitano, good catch, thanks. I added a correction.

Comment: I think that the post @cigien linked answered the question as I understood it (I didn't even think about what the size was bound to), but I like this point! (I wish I could upvote!)